# Terraform cidrsubnet function

Tags: terraform, subnet

First of all, I apologize for now knowing how to subnet better. It's not something I've had to do up until now.

I have been given a network/cidr of 10.10.32.0/19.

I have 6 subnets that need 255 ips each.

The rest of the IPs I would like to spread across 3 remaining subnets.

This is what i came up with using cidrsubnet

```
        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 2, 0) # "10.10.64.0/21" 2048 hosts
        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 2, 1) # "10.10.72.0/21" 2048 hosts
        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 2, 2) # "10.10.80.0/21" 2048 hosts

        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 5, 24) # "10.10.88.0/24" 255 hosts
        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 5, 25) # "10.10.89.0/24" 255 hosts
        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 5, 26) # "10.10.90.0/24" 255 hosts

        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 5, 27) # "10.10.91.0/24" 255 hosts
        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 5, 28) # "10.10.92.0/24" 255 hosts
        cidrsubnet("10.10.32.0/19", 5, 29) # "10.10.93.0/24" 255 hosts
```

This leaves me with about 512 ips that can't be used. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the issue?

Comment: The question would be am I subnetting correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You have `2^11` (32-19) hosts == `8192`

Your range begins at `10.10.32.0` and runs through `10.10.63.255`

`6*256+3*2048 == 7680` leaving the 512

You'll need to rebalance so you don't waste IPs.

Your first `cidrsubnet(10.10.32/19,2,0)` is `10.10.32.0--10.10.39.255`

Comment: Can you explain more about what it means to rebalance your ips?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was unclear. It was late at night when I replied. You want to have subnets that consume all your (8192) IPs and not leave 512 unused. You specified 6*256 and to smear the remaining across 3 but that doesn't give you equally sized subets (8192-6*256)/3=2218.666... So you can't do it.  You could have 6*256, 2*2048, 1*2560 but that's a little gnarly. I don't know what your requirements are but I was proposing making the distribution more consistent (and complete).